# OCLazyLoad with MVC Bundles

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

I use MVC bundling to bundle JS files:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/essentialjs").Include(
                                  "~/Scripts/spa/features/exception/exceptionModule.js",
                                  "~/Scripts/spa/features/exception/controllers/errorController.js"                    
            ));
```

I need to load these MVC bundles using OCLazyLoad. I attempted the code below but get a 404 for the bundle not found.

```
.state('test',
      {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "scripts/test.html",
        resolve: {
          plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            console.log('oczload');
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
              { type: 'js', path: '~/bundles/essentialjs' }
            ]);
          }]
        }
      })
```

The issue appears to be on this line:

```
 { type: 'js', path: '~/bundles/essentialjs' }
```

Comment: have you tried with just `/bundles/essentialjs`. Not sure if `~/` is a valid url... If you want to refer to current directory, you need to use `./bundles/essentialjs`

Comment: Do you mean change it in both the BundleConfig and Angular to use `/bundles/essentialjs`?

Comment: Yes...both places

Comment: Although I not sure about your bundle though. It does have some strange .net like syntax.. So my guess would only be to change it in UI router state